# SQL Insert with where conditions for all fields

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere, sql-insert

I have a question about the SQL. There is a table with 3 fields.

- ID (auto number by access)
- First Name (Text)
- Last Name (Text)

The following is the data

Data

```
ID   FirstName     LastName
============================
1    John          Chan
2    May           Wong
3    Tim           Leung
```

I want to insert the first name and last name to the table, but the first name and last name must not be the same from the existing data in table. For example, it is okay when I enter John Lee and Tim Wong, but not Tim Leung.

Can I use 1 SQL to finish this part? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming TSql:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (FirstName, LastName)
SELECT @FirstName, @LastName FROM myTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM myTable 
    WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName)
```

As others suggest, adding a unique constraint to enforce this rule is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

No. But you can set first name and last name as unique constraint.

You can also check if there is any row with the same first name and last name before insert.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX index_name ON table_name (first_name, last_name);
or:
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index_name ON table_name (first_name, last_name);

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE last_name = 'Leung' and first_name = 'Tim'"))==0) { 
 //add the names 
}else{
    echo "First name - last name exists."
}
```

Php style.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  @bort suggest is fine.  But if you want to update the existing rows and insert new rows in one SQL statement take a look at the merge statement.

http://dcx.sybase.com/1100/en/dbreference_en11/merge-statement.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an `INDEX` for this ([***see CREATE INDEX (Transact-SQL)***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx))

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX uniqueName_Index 
       ON TableName (first_name, last_name);
```